# CoffeeScript - watch and compile "*.coffee" files with a prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, coffeescript

I would like to compile CoffeeScript files in a directory and output the files with a prefix (`.coffee` in my case).

For instance, I have this file structure :

- fileA.js
- fileB.js
- filaA.coffee
- fileB.coffee

I want to be able to compile (and watch) `*.coffee` files, and compile them like so :

- fileA.js
- fileB.js
- filaA.coffee
- fileB.coffee
- .coffee.fileA.js
- .coffee.fileB.js

Note that the `.js` files are unchanged.
How can I do that (preferably in my bash shell) ?

So that would be the equivalent of the following hardcoded solution, but for all `.coffee` files in a directory :

`coffee --watch --compile -p myfile.coffee > .coffee.myfile.js`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this? I am not sure how to do this, but you can always use **folder options** to place your coffee compiled files to a separate folder... You could also fork coffee command: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/command.js.

Comment: @lazlojuly because I just happen to have this in a project in which I need to modify files, but I did not find any build script (coffeescript is not used anywhere else in this repository, so I guess this was an attempt that wasn't convincing).

Comment: Since it was just a quick fix, I went with launching it by hand from the console for the necessary files. I would still be interested in a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I just leave it here =)

```
"scripts": {
  "compile-coffee": "for i in src/**/*.coffee; do coffee --compile --print $i > $i.js; done",
  "watch-coffee": "for i in src/**/*.coffee; do coffee --compile --watch --join $i.coffee.js -- $i; done",
},
```